# How do I work out the average of two columns? Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

I'm currently making a report on Microsoft Access 2013. I've created a query first and then selected the appropriate tables and fields.

The last two fields of my current query are:

CourseworkMarks

Examination Marks

Both fields contains a number between 1-100. But I want to calculate the average of both fields.

I've included an image for this:

Thanks.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oENT5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be (in the GUI designer):

```
AverageMarks: (CourseworkMarks+ExaminationMarks)/2
```

Comment: I tried your answer but its asking me for a parameter value?

Comment: @jon are the last two columns calculations in this query? Or are they aliases? Substitute aliases for absolute references (whatever the calculation is, retype into this expression in place of the field names). That's the most common cause of the parameter value issue.

Comment: Yes, you have probably misspelled a field name.

Comment: @Gustav thanks, I've fixed it. Thank you for the help